# Cannot resolve symbol '@style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat'

Tags: java, android, android-theme, android-styles

I'm trying to run my Android project and then Android Studio shows me the
following error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol '@style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat'
```

```
<style name="AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light" parent="@style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light">
</style>
<style name="Animation.AppCompat.Dialog" parent="@style/Base.Animation.AppCompat.Dialog">
</style>
<style name="Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp" parent="@style/Base.Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp">
</style>
<style name="Animation.AppCompat.Tooltip" parent="@style/Base.Animation.AppCompat.Tooltip">
</style>
<style name="Animation.Design.BottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/Animation.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/design_bottom_sheet_slide_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/design_bottom_sheet_slide_out</item>
</style>
```

What should I do to resolve it?

Comment: Share your code. There's nothing to do with a single line error.

Answer (score 0):

implement right appcompat at app/build.gradle file

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add android support design library .
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
and

```
def appcompat_version = "1.3.1"
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
// For loading and tinting drawables on older versions of the platform
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:$appcompat_version"
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

this will solve your issue .